# How does a Wehnelt electrode both extract and focus electrons?

Tags: optics, electrostatics

Now that I can [try to pronounce it](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/55539/38291) I'd like to understand how a [Wehnelt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wehnelt_cylinder) lens, grid, cap, etc. extracts electrons from a cathode and simultaneously focuses them.

Naively I'd think that it would have a positive potential with respect to the filament in order to produce a field strong enough to overcome at least part of the work function and convince the electrons to leave the cathode material and enter free space, but it also appears to have a repulsive force on them in order to produce a converging beam, at least as shown in the diagram below, which may be incomplete.

How does this work?

[image: Wehnelt cap]  [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Wehnelt_cap.svg)

Comment: Consider the field lines between the tip at one potential and the cup at a different potential.

Comment: @JonCuster that's exactly the problem. If the field lines are attractive in order to pull the electrons into free space, then they will also present a diverging, not converging force. By convention, they will start at the sharp edges of the circular hole in the Wehnelt and converge near the point of the filament. That's why I suggested that the drawing may be incomplete.

Comment: But the aren’t attractive- the cup is at negative potential, but not as negative as the filament. An electron going straight through the hole sees no tangential force, those at an angle are pushed laterally. Adjusting the relative potential alters the angle and hence the focal length.

Comment: @JonCuster If the Wehnelt is indeed positive relative to the filament (your "not as negative as the filament") then the lateral push will be *away from the axis* and towards the sharp edges of the circular hole in the Wehnelt, not towards the axis; i.e. diverging not converging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does a Wehnelt electrode both extract and focus electrons?

It doesn't. Since it is biased negative with respect to the cathode it would suppress electron emission rather than extract them if it were the only electrode.

Instead, the anode further down stream is positive with respect to the cathode and the opening in the Wehnelt is sufficiently large that the anode still produces a net attractive field at the cathode's surface. Once they leave the cathode the Wehnelt's circular aperture's effect is to repel the electrons, forcing them back towards the axis and thereby producing an image of the cathode downstream, or at least a crossover.

See slide 14 of [Presentation on Electron Sources Chapter 5](http://web.eng.fiu.edu/wangc/Electron%20Sources%20Presentation.pdf) which shows the same drawing as a Quora answer to [What is an electron gun?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-electron-gun):

[image: Quora: What is an electron gun?]

Comment: +1 this is exactly what's going on, OP forgot about the anode voltage after the Wehnalt cap.

Comment: @KFGauss thanks! OP is forgetful for sure. It seems they went off and read further then wrote this answer ;-)